# Requesting URL and Parsing The Result In A Alert

Tags: swift, swiftui, alamofire, swifty-json

I have made the variables global, but I have not been able to figure out how to show the alert after it has gotten the response. Not sure if I have to create function or not. Anything would be helpful.

Code: https://hastebin.com/izurihadib.swift

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingAlert = false
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            var str1 = ""
            var fullStr = ""
            Button(action: {
                self.showingAlert = true
                AF.request("https://api-quiz.hype.space/shows/now").responseJSON { response in
                    switch response.result {
                       case .success(let value):
                        let json = JSON(value)
                        debugPrint(json)
                        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
                        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
                        let dt = dateFormatter.date(from: json["nextShowTime"].stringValue)
                        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
                        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy h:mm a"
                        let nextGameName = json["upcoming"][0]["nextShowLabel"]["title"].stringValue
                        let tempStr1 = "Next Game: "
                        str1 = tempStr1 + nextGameName
                        let nextGamePrize = json["nextShowPrize"].stringValue
                        let tempStr2 = "Prize: "
                        let str2 = tempStr2 + nextGamePrize
                        let nextGameTime = dateFormatter.string(from: dt!)
                        let tempStr3 = "Date/Time: "
                        let str3 = tempStr3 + nextGameTime
                        fullStr = str2 + "\n" + str3
                    
                    case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                    }
                }
            }) {
                Text("Get Info")
            }
            .alert(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
                Alert(title: Text(str1), message: Text(fullStr), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
                    }
             .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "phone.fill")
                Text("First Tab")
              }
           Text("The content of the second view")
             .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "tv.fill")
                Text("Second Tab")
              }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not post your code on some other website, try to make it easy for those that may choose to help you. Please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Try putting the `self.showingAlert = true` inside the success case of your network reques.t

Comment: it still shows a blank alert.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the changes you need to make to fix your issue.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingAlert = false
    @State private var str1 = ""
    @State private var fullStr = ""
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Button(action: {
                self.showingAlert = true
                AF.request("https://api-quiz.hype.space/shows/now").responseJSON { response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success(let value):
                        //...
                    case .failure(let error):
                        self.str1 = "Error"
                        self.fullStr = "\(error)"
                        self.showingAlert = true
                    }
                }
            }) {
                Text("Get Info")
            }
            .alert(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
                Alert(title: Text(str1), message: Text(fullStr), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
            }
            //...
        }
    }
}
```